# disksim + sdd extension 64 bits

Tags: compilation, 64-bit, simulator, solid-state-drive

I am trying to use DiskSim with the SSD model in a 64 bits environment. I found out that Microsoft has created an SSD model for DiskSim 4.0. However, I couldn't compile it as my computer is 64 bits.

I saw that Western Digital released a modified version of DiskSim 4.0 that makes it 64 bits compliant but I couldn't make it work with the SSD model.

I also saw that MSR's SSD model which is not compatible with Western Digital release.

Could anyone tell me please if there is a way to compile DiskSim 4.0 + SSS model on a 64 bits environment?

Answer (score 1):

1. unzip ssdmodel and patch ssd file

   ```
   $ patch -p1 < ssdmodel/ssd-patch
   ```
2. patch file "modify-patch"

   ```
   $ patch -p1 < modify-patch
   ```

   if you just want it run in a 32 bit PC, directly perform `make`
3. patch the 64-bit patch file

   ```
   $ patch -p1 < 64bit-patch
   ```

modify-patch：https://github.com/cighao/disksim-4.0-with-ssdmodel-patch

The most important thing was to patch the file "64bit-patch" which can be find at 
https://github.com/cighao/disksim-4.0-with-ssdmodel-64bit-patch.